# C# 2D Drawing custom style of lines and curves

Tags: c#, drawing, system.drawing, system.drawing.graphics

I build an application which part is also drawing into video frames. For this I am using Graphics library from `System.Drawing`. `Drawing` is working fine and is already implemented. But I also need to be able to draw straight lines with for example this kind of curvy pattern:

[image: Picture for better understanding].

Could somebody help me how this could be achievable?

Comment: If you don't find anything already implemented, I guess you could chain some `DrawCurve` or `DrawBezier` together yourself?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it too. I just wanted to ask first if there is not some easier way or something already implemented.

Comment: There's nothing specific. If you already have the points that define the spline, you can add them to a GraphicsPath object (with `GraphicsPath.AddCurve()`, for example). It will generate the bezier curve for you. You can then just use `Graphics.DrawPath()` to draw it. Mind the `Tension` argument value.

Comment: You can use a [Sine wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) (`sinusoid`) to generate those points, for example.

Comment: No, such a wiggly or shaped Pen doesn't exist. Sounds like a nice exercise to create one. Jimi's advice is probably the way to go: Calculate the turning points and the add a series of arcs to a GrphicsPath..

Comment: On 2nd thought I think you can get away by using a regular Pen and DrawCurves. You need to calculate a List<PointF>  the go along the length of the line and vyray to both sides be some distance (half the width of the curves)..

Comment: `public void Draw(Graphics g, Point a, Point b)
{
    float lx = b.X - a.X;
    float ly = b.Y - a.Y;
    float dx = 0;
    float dy = 0;
    float ll = (float)Math.Sqrt(lx * lx + ly * ly);
    float scale = WiggleLength / ll;
    if (lx != 0) dy = ly * scale;
    if (ly != 0) dx = lx * scale;
    int c = 0;`

Comment: ..`List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    while (c < 1f / scale)
        {
        float oo = (c % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) * (c % 4 == 0 ? 1 : -1) * WiggleWidth / 10f;
        PointF n = new PointF(a.X + c * dx - oo * dy, a.Y + c * dy + oo * dx);
        points.Add(n);
        c++;
    }
    g.DrawCurve(pen, points.ToArray(), WiggleTension);
}`